# In a URI, what does the suffix ".do" stand for?

Tags: url-rewriting, url

I see URI ending in ".do" on some enterprise websites. I've always been curious to know what that stands for, but my Google searches have so far not turned up an answer.

Here is an example from ATT customer portal:

https://www.att.com/view/displayFullBill.do

What does the ".do" mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Java Servlets.

...Or more specifically, [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/), and it means "do" as in "perform an action", URLs are usually mapped to the Controllers within an MVC architecture, and "do" is just a convention, any URL can be mapped (and other languages/frameworks could use the same URL structure), having ".do" doesn't do anything special.

Comment: I think this is actually the more accurate answer here.

Comment: I moved the green check over to this answer. Thanks, Ewan.

Answer (score 3):

[Java Servlets](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/do)

Comment: I wonder where they get "do" out of that unless it's used as a verb.

Comment: It is used in the verb sense because refers to an action that the application is to carry out. The application 'does' something then sends you to a new page that displays the results of the action.